# How to get the div id's in a div in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do you get the id's in a div?

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="frag-123">ass</div>
   <div id="frag-123">ass</div>
   <div id="frag-123">ass</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: They should not have the same ID to begin with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. You can use [`map()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map):

```
var ids = $("#container").children().map(function(n, i) {
  return n.id;
});
```

or [`each()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each):

```
$("#container").children().each(function(n, i) {
  var id = this.id;
  // do something with it
});
```

etc

Comment: $("div#container").children('div').map(function(){ return this.id });

Comment: Will this also get the dynamically created DIVS using JQuery? Thanks!

Comment: If the divs are created and in the DOM at the time you run this, yes.

Comment: hi cletus, thank you again for the help. I have a follow-up question through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457637/how-do-you-pass-an-array-string-to-a-web-service-via-jquery

Comment: Good one.Little typo: it should be var ids = ...function(i,n) instead of  ...function(n,i)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
attr('id')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div', $('div#container')).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

to get them as an array of strings

```
var ids = $.map($('#container div'), function(n,i) {
              return n.id
          });
```