# how do you pass an array string[] to a Web Service via Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asmx

here's my code:

```
var ids = $.map($("#container-1").children(), function(n, i) {
     return n.id;
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Loader.asmx/Active',
    data: "{'divs':'" + ids + "'}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript;

```
var ids = $.map($("#container-1").children(), function(n, i) {
     return n.id;
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Loader.asmx/Active',
    data: { divs: ids.join("|") },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {}
});
```

in C#:

```
string[] arrIds = divs.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think you'd need to render your data as a string.

Wouldn't this work?

```
data: { divs: ids },
```

Assuming that ids is a JavaScript string array, that is.