# asp.net : how to send a array from client to server web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

In ASP.NET, I have collected a list of selected items from a checkbox in an array at the client side. Now I need to pass the array from client to server's ASMX web method. How do I do this?

Comment: Is it an ASMX Web Service you're using on the backend? Are you using any JavaScript libraries?

Comment: yes,using ASMX web service & jquery

Comment: what is the question? is it a trouble of converting a List to an Array (solution: List<T>.ToArray() ) or what?

Comment: The problem is, i have the contents in an array at client side,I need to pass that array to web method and convert that array into list on the server. But i have trouble in passing array from client to server side's web method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you pass an array string\[\] to a Web Service via Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457637/how-do-you-pass-an-array-string-to-a-web-service-via-jquery)

Comment: I'll check that question and update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a JSON library to your page, use [json2.js here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). That gives you a function to serialize javascript arrays into JSON strings.

You can then pass it into your webmethod:

```
[WebMethod] 
public void MyWebMethod(List<string> someValues)
{
    // Use someValues...
}
```

Here's the javascript you need

```
var arrayData = ["1","2","3"]; // Your array goes here

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MyWebService.asmx/MyWebMethod",
  data: JSON.stringify({ someValues: arrayData }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function() 
  {
    // Your success function...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Client-Side Web Service Calls with AJAX Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx)

[Calling Web Services from Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398995.aspx)