# JS insert in array, and fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys :) I can make this with PHP, but iam trying to make with JS. I have some div like this:

```
<div class="content" id="2"> This is message </div>
<div class="content" id="43"> Hello </div>
<div class="content" id="21"> some content... </div>
```

I want to get all **"id"** attributes inside in **"content"** class. And the all of the **""text""** aswell...

Have to looks like : `x = array(2, 43, 21)` and `y= array(this is message, Hello, some content)`
After this i want to fetch foreach ...

```
foreach () {
echo x;
echo y  }
```

Want to looks like this :

```
2 this is message 

43 Hello

21 some content
```

Comment: `Have to looks like` says who?  What is this for?  What have you tried?  Is this homework?

Comment: You can probably find answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453504/how-to-get-the-div-ids-in-a-div-in-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854009/jquery-get-content-between-div-tags)

Comment: @junaid this is different question.

Comment: @halid96 is it? The point is, if you won't research about your issue then even try? You can simply hire a programmer to do it for you.

Comment: @halid96 is it? The point is, if you won't research about your issue then even try? You can simply hire a programmer to do it for you.

Comment: @Juniad absolotely true, in generally i am researching the steps 1 by 1, but now i am lazy becouse the time is 01:11 :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to assign each of the DOM elements to a list with `document.getElementsByClassName`, and then loop through each of these, outputting based on the index in the loop. You can grab the ID and content of each of the elements with `.id` and `innerHTML` respectively.

This could be done with something similar to the following:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  console.log(list[i].id, list[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="2"> This is message </div>
<div class="content" id="43"> Hello </div>
<div class="content" id="21"> some content... </div>
```

If you want to actually replace the contents to the DOM itself, rather than simply log to the console, you can use `document.innerHTML`:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].innerHTML = list[i].id + list[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="2"> This is message </div>
<div class="content" id="43"> Hello </div>
<div class="content" id="21"> some content... </div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you very much dude :) wish you happy life, i will try it